# Cisco LEAP Vulnerable using WPAv2?

Tags: cisco

I'm using WPAv2 with Cisco LEAP and I want to know how secure this setup is? From what I've heard there are vulnerabilities in LEAP, but the current security standard is WPAv2. Can someone help me understand this a little bit better?

I'm an IT person for a small company with limited network experience and no formal training.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much spot on; WPA2 is still considered pretty secure, but if you've got it tied to an authentication scheme that's extremely vulnerable like LEAP, then you're losing a lot of the security that WPA2 gets you.

To be clear, the risks of using WPA2 with a weak authentication scheme are different from the risks of, say, using WEP.  Data in transit over the network between the access point and a client once a session is established isn't at risk as it would be with WEP.  But what is at risk is the authentication session - users' passwords are exposed via a weak hash during this process, and an attacker can even de-authenticate already associated users to force them to resend the vulnerable LEAP negotiation.

In essence: move off of LEAP if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks Shane. Can anyone recommend a tutorial on how to securely configure a Cisco Wireless AP?